# Proving that $\int_{0}^{1}\left(\zeta(t)+\frac{1}{1-t}\right)dt=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma_{n}}{(n+1)!}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, summation, riemann-zeta, stieltjes-constants

It seems that the above identity is true. Can this be proven? Or are there references treating sums like the right hand side?

The above constants, $\gamma_{n}$, are the Stieltjes constants.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a quick search in wikipedia:
$$
\zeta \left( 1+z \right) =\frac{1}{z}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _nz^n}
$$
So
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1{\left( \zeta \left( t \right) +\frac{1}{1-t} \right) \mathrm{d}t}=&\int_0^1{\left( \zeta \left( 1+\left( t-1 \right) \right) -\frac{1}{t-1} \right) \mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\int_0^1{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _n\left( t-1 \right) ^n}\mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\gamma _n}{n!}}\int_0^1{\left( 1-t \right) ^n\mathrm{d}t}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\gamma _n}{\left( n+1 \right) !}}
\end{align*}
The only question now is why we can interchange the sum with the integral. From the same article, we have
$$
\left| \gamma _n \right|\leqslant \frac{n!}{2^{n+1}}
$$
Therefore when $t\in [0,1]$
\begin{align*}
\left| \sum_{n=0}^N{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _n\left( t-1 \right) ^n} \right|&\leqslant \sum_{n=0}^N{\left| \frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _n\left( t-1 \right) ^n \right|}\leqslant \sum_{n=0}^N{\frac{\left| \gamma _n \right|}{n!}}\left( 1-t \right) ^n
\\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^N{\left( \frac{1-t}{2} \right) ^n}\leqslant \frac{1}{1+t}\leqslant 1
\end{align*}
By dominated convergence theorem:
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _n\left( t-1 \right) ^n}\mathrm{d}t}=&\int_0^1{\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _n\left( t-1 \right) ^n}\mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1{\sum_{n=0}^N{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n}{n!}\gamma _n\left( t-1 \right) ^n}\mathrm{d}t}
\\
=&\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=0}^N{\frac{1}{n!}\gamma _n\int_0^1{\left( 1-t \right) ^n}}\mathrm{d}t
\\
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\gamma _n}{n!}}\int_0^1{\left( 1-t \right) ^n\mathrm{d}t}
\end{align*}